# how to add unique values to Queue using muti-threading?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public static class MutiThread extends Thread {

private Queue<String> waitingQue = new LinkedList<>();
private String intake;
public MutiThread (String str) {
    intake = str;
}

public void run() {
    Pattern p =Pattern.compile("\\d");
    Matcher m=p.matcher(intake);
    while (m.find()){
        String temp = m.group();
        if (!waitingQue.contains(temp)){
            waitingQue.add(temp);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(waitingQue);
}


}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   MutiThread t1 = new MutiThread("112236");
   t1.start();
   MutiThread t2 = new MutiThread("1122345");
   t2.start();
}
```

I have a thread class that takes in a string and check if the string matches certain pattern and if yes and if it does not exist in the queue list it will be added.
The problem is, I want to use multi threading to add unique values to the queue, each thread starts and go into the thread class and add one unique value to the queue.
My expected output is queue value = "123456" however the code above only gives me "1236" or either "12345"
how should i do that?

Comment: Each Thread has its own `waitingQueue`

Comment: Also your class name has a typo `MutiThread` should be `MultiThread`

Comment: I would recommend using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` instead of `LinkedList`

Answer (score 0):

The problem(not really) is that each instance of `MultiThread` has its own instance of the queue.

If you were suggesting that this can be a concurrency issue, well it is not, or at least not at this point. To have concurrency issues more threads need to share access to same object(s).